# How to interrupt a function while running in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, interrupt, micropython

I am programming a couple of LEDs to make a clone of Philips Hue or LIFX for personal needs as a beginner project. My goal is to learn more about hardware and software. I've written some code that works perfectly, but I have a function that needs more time to go through all the colors. How can I interrupt it from running so I can process the request I've received by the client (in this case a python script running on my computer)? I have an esp8266 acting as a server. And this code runs on the microcontroller. I tried checking with if statements if a request has been sent after every cycle, but it takes a lot longer than I want it to.

```
def color_wheel(leds):
    for x in range(255):
        for y in range(30):
            leds[y] = (255, x, 0)
        leds.write()

    for x in range(255):
        for y in range(30):
            leds[y] = (255 - x, 255, 0)
        leds.write()

    for x in range(255):
        for y in range(30):
            leds[y] = (0, 255, x)
        leds.write()

    for x in range(255):
        for y in range(30):
            leds[y] = (0, 255 - x, 255)
        leds.write()

    for x in range(255):
        for y in range(30):
            leds[y] = (x, 0, 255)
        leds.write()

    for x in range(255):
        for y in range(30):
            leds[y] = (255, 0, 255 - x)
        leds.write()
```

Comment: you may want to look at [`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep)

Comment: Did you have a look at asyncio? How did you implement the requests?

Comment: The esp8266 is a very simple server that listens on TCP port 2525. All it does is listen and wait for a request. As soon as a request is sent from my computer, it stores the data in a dictionary and sets the settings accordingly. For example if I send a JSON object to change the color. It changes the color successfully. What I can't do successfully is the following: If I want to start animating the LEDs I need a function that runs indefinitely until it's interrupted with another request. And this is the thing I don't know how to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are running a loop like that:

```
while True:
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if data:
        handle_data(data)
```

That works if handle_data does not block the loop for too long. But if your color wheel takes several seconds, no data can be received in this time.
You could implement handle data to return a generator instead, and iterate over it:

```
def color_wheel():
    color=[255,0,0]
    for rgb, direction in [(1,1), (0,-1), (2,1), (1,-1), (0,1),(2,-1)]:
        for x in range(255):       
            color[rgb]+=direction
            yield(tuple(color)

def set_color(color):
    yield(color)

def handle_data(data):
    #depending on data return set_color() or color_wheel()


while True:
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if data:
        color_gen=handle_data(data)
    try:
        color=next(color_gen)
    except StopIteration:
        #no new color
        pass
    finally:
        for y in range(30):
            leds[y] = color
        leds.write()
```

Alternatively, if you want to do more things in parallel, you could use asyncio.

Answer (score 0):

Best of luck with your beginner project.

Do you mean to stop control flow(loop)? If so please check the "break" Option.

Please refer to section 4.4 in the below link for more details.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I want to stop the control flow, and I know how break works and how to use it. The thing I can't wrap my head around is how to stop the function immediately as I receive the client request to the server efficiently. Do I need to use multiple threads for that? I want to stop the function execution the moment I receive a request for a change of color or effect. The LEDs should never stop the animation while receiving a request especially if the request is invalid. Is there a way to do what I'm asking with different threads?